# warning: division by zero

Tags: php

I am using the following static method for sending mail alerts, but its throwing an error: `warning:division by zero` ...

```
Postman::MailAlert($_POST['email'],'Hello '.$_POST['name'].', Thanks for signing up.Your customer id is '.$_POST['city']/'/'.$product_id.'.');
```

I have solved this issue by putting @, but why is this issue raised, and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: PHP.net : `Currently the "@" error-control operator prefix will even disable error reporting for critical errors that will terminate script execution. Among other things, this means that if you use "@" to suppress errors from a certain function and either it isn't available or has been mistyped, the script will die right there with no indication as to why.` So it doesn't solve issue, it makes that issue ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just the problem part:

```
$_POST['city']/'/'.$product_id.'.');
```

Need to change like this.

```
$_POST['city'] . '/'.$product_id.'.');
```

Comment: If it solved your problem, please tick my answer as correct, thank you. :)

Comment: oh right that was my mistake, i think it would be fixed now, thanks.

Comment: this app is asking me to wait for 5 minutes before i mark it as answer

Comment: @seoppc now try again, please :)

Answer (score 2):

Near the end of that line of code:

```
[...]$_POST['city']/'/'[...]
```

Add some spaces to make it clear:

```
[...] $_POST['city'] / '/' [...]
```

You're trying to divide `$_POST['city']` by `'/'`.  If non-numeric strings (`'/'`) are interpreted by PHP as having a numeric value of 0, then you're dividing by 0.

Maybe you meant to concatenate instead of divide?

Comment: I guess it's just a typo

Answer (score 1):

you should use

```
Postman::MailAlert($_POST['email'],'Hello '.$_POST['name'].', Thanks for signing up.Your customer id is '.$_POST['city'].'/'.$product_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST['city']/'/'` should become `$_POST['city'].'/'`, common mistake when you type fast

Answer (score 1):

$_POST['city']/  <--- what is this slash doing here? I believe it's redundant. ;)

And just a side note - do you sanitize user input? I see you are directly using the $_POST array variables - don't do it. Users might submit just about anything here, even some nasty strings, and it's your responsibility to make sure that these won't compromise your application.

P.S.: Adding @ is a bad practice, since it only suppresses the error messages (removing the symptoms) while not fixing the cause.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php